# Modernizr.load deprecated, what should I use?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, modernizr

I'm using modernizr with a customs js, and now that I try to change my projecto to ruby on rails, is marking an error I checked many comments and it say that modernizr.load is deprecated what should I use? 
this is the code how I used the modernizr with my custom.js :

```
    Modernizr.load([
      {
        load: '/assets/javascripts/superfish.js',
        complete: function () {

            //Main menu
            jQuery('#main-menu').superfish({
                delay: 400,
                speed: 'fast',
                cssArrows: false
            });

        }
      }
    ]); 

if (jQuery('.punica-carousel-1').length > 0) {

    Modernizr.load([
      {
        load: '/assets/owl.carousel.js',
        complete: function () {
            jQuery('.punica-carousel-1').owlCarousel({
                items : 5,
                itemsDesktop : [979,3],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [767,2],
                itemsTablet : [639,2],
                itemsMobile : [479,1],
                lazyLoad : true,
                navigation : true,
                pagination: false,
                navigationText : false
            });
        }
      }
    ]);
};
```

I really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem replacing `Modernizr.load` with `yepnope`, but using the `v1.5.4`  old release, not the newest one.